# how to stop dulicate entry and missing sequence while updating a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am taking max invoice no. from a table and incrementing 1 in it and updating the same table with the incremented value, the problem is that multiple users are performing this operation, so some time its misses the sequence and some time is generating same sequence for different jobs. I can't make invoice no field unique as for other jobs its is 0.
the code is like.

```
$res=mysql_query("select max(invoice_no) from complaints_master");
$result=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$code_id=$result[0]+1;
// update invoice details in complaint master
$usr="update complaints_master set invoice_no='$code_id', invoice_flag='1', invoice_date='$today', invoice_total_amt='$_POST[final_total]' where job_no='$_REQUEST[job_no]'";
```

Comment: what about while updating to use select subquery, instead of 2 queries

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the transaction level to `SERIALIZABLE` to ensure each `MAX(invoice_no)+1` returns a unique value to the client. Not sure how you do that while using PHP, but here is the MySQL doc: [MySQL SET TRANSACTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-transaction.html).